# How to determine a control size in twips?

Tags: vb.net, data-conversion, richtext

I'm developing VB.net application in MS Visual Studio 2019 (community Edition) in which I programatically paste an image from the clipboard into a Richtextbox.

I need to add an option to force that image to completely fill the control's visible area.

Examining the richtext which results from pasting the image, and then again after I've manually dragged the image to resize it to fill the control, it looks like all I need to do is change the picwgoal and pichgoal rtf tags for the image to the dimensions of the control.

The problem is that picwgoal and pichgoal are in twips.

So my question is: Is there a reliable way to dynamically calculate a control's dimensions in twips from it's pixel width and height, such that it will work when the app runs in various resolutions/scaling ?

I understand that the TwipsPerPixelX method is obsolete and not compatable with 64 bit processes.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

..Think I've worked it out myself

..Think I've worked it out myself

assuming a point is always 1/72 inches and a point is 20 twips..

```
Dim g = Me.CreateGraphics()
Dim RTBxTwips = (RTB.Width * 72 / g.DpiX) * 20
Dim RTByTwips = (RTB.Height * 72 / g.DpiY) * 20
g.Dispose()
```

..seems to give results equal to the picwgoal and pichgoal tags for an image resized to the controls visible area